comparing multiple proportions between three groups
Let's say I have a program that generates characters for a game. There are three types of characters: animal, human, and spirit. It also generates a "strength" rating for each character. The ratings are ranked on a scale from weakest to strongest: 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 2/2, and 3/3.
For reasons I won't go into, a 2/2 is stronger than a 2/3, and 3/3 is stronger than 2/2.
The data looks like this:



ch_type
total_obs
1/3
1/2
2/3
2/2
3/3




animal
13
0
7
0
5
1


human
285
4
41
17
127
96


spirit
60
2
1
11
12
34



The following plot shows counts (N) of how many times a character of each type was generated, human characters were generated far more than spirit or animal characters. Each pie chart shows the division of strength rankings.

Thus, of the 285 human characters that were generated, 96 of them (33.7%) were generated with a strength rating of 3/3.
I'm interested in comparing the slices between the pies, and seeing if the type of character influences the proportion of each strength ranking. So I believe the independent variable would be the type of character (animal, human, spirit) and the response variable would be the proportion of a given strength rank.
For example, from just a visual inspection of this plot, it looks like spirit characters are more likely to have 3/3 strength rating compared to human and animal characters. Meanwhile, human characters are more likely to have a 2/2 strength rating compared to animal and spirit characters, and so on.
Given the present data, is it feasible to do some kind of formal significance testing? And if so, what would be the best test to do it?

One possibility for analyzing this data is the compositional data approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compositional-data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~sayan/Sta613/2018/CoDaNutshell.pdf

Another option would be to fit a binomial GLM and look for a non-zero "interaction" between type-of-character and strength level. That is, $g{\left(\mathrm{Proportion}\right)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mathrm{CharacterType} + \beta_2 \mathrm{StrengthCategory} + \beta_3 \mathrm{CharacterType}\  \mathrm{StrengthCategory}$

I'm familiar with GLM's, but in a binomial GLM, the response variable g is categorical right? Wouldn't proportion be a continuous variable? (i.e 0%-100%)

You got the proportions from somewhere, right?

There are also ways to model proportions or counts directly as such. The point is that you're testing for interaction in a linear model, maybe with a likelihood ratio test.
